# iOS Core Graphics PDF memory managment problem

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, core-graphics

I'm reading PDF file, and then releasing it:

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), (CFStringRef)@"somepdf.pdf", NULL, NULL);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);    
int pagesCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
```

But the memory is not freed after release (checked that with Instruments). Why? What i'm missing in memory managment.

Thanks.

EDIT

here is my code:

```
- (void)loadView {
            [super loadView];
            CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), (CFStringRef)@"some.pdf", NULL, NULL);
            pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL); 
            CFRelease(pdfURL);
            CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);

            TiledPDFView * v = [[TiledPDFView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andScale:1];
            [v setPage:pdfPage];

            [self.view addSubview:v];


            UIButton * but = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [but setTitle:@"removeView" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [but addTarget:self action:@selector(tests) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            but.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40);
            [self.view addSubview:but];

    }

    -(void) tests {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view release];
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
    }
```

`pdf` is instance variable.
`TiledPDFView` - is uiview from ZoomingPDFViewer example. it draws `CGPDFPageRef` using `CATiledLayer`.

after i call `tests` method, the view is removed (becomes invisible), but the memory allocated with `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL` is not freed.

Comment: `CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`. `size_t` is unsigned, whereas `int` is signed, and `size_t` may be larger (in bytes, and thereby in range) than `int`. Beware of large documents that have seemingly-negative (actually just very large) numbers of pages, or that have effectively random numbers of pages (when `size_t` is larger than `int` and your number is so big that it exceeds the range of `int`, so part of the number gets lopped off). You should always use the correct type for the values you're working with.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

What memory is not released? As you say, you duly released the CGPDFDocument, so that should have gone away.

Are you sure it's not the CFURL that's sticking around? You don't show yourself releasing that, but you Copied it, so you are obliged to. See [the Memory Management Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/).

You can use the ObjectAlloc instrument to determine which specific objects are remaining alive. Set the beginning and end points in the timeline to before the object was created and after it was freed, respectively, then set the instrument to show you “Objects Created & Still Living”. You can also use the Leaks instrument to show you what objects are still living that you no longer have a pointer to. Both instruments initially show a breakdown by class, into which you can drill down to instances and then events (allocations, retentions, autoreleases, releases, and deallocations).

Comment: The memory which is allocated with CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL is not freed (~3MB is allocated and still used). I edited my code in question

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting the `self.view` property to `nil` rather than releasing the view you still hold onto? Also, have you verified that the page (which I assume the view retained) got released?